# How do you change of variables in integrals (i.e. dxdy into dudv)?

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

I was looking around the internet for a simple(r) proof of the Gamma Reflection Formula. I found this: Detailed explanation of the Γ reflection formula understandable by an AP Calculus student, and did not understand how they got from the dxdy integral to a dudv integral:

To quote: "$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{-z}t^{z-1}e^{-(s+t)}\,ds\, dt \qquad (0<\Re z <1)$$

With the new variables $u = s + t, v = t/s$ this gives
$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{v^{z-1}}{1+v}e^{-u}\,du\, dv $$"

Can anyone help me? Explanations understandable by an AP Calculus student would be great! If this needs stuff that AP Calculus doesn't cover, explanations of how those work and why or references to other sources would be excellent.

Comment: I'm not sure, but do you already know know how to change the limits for the double integral? It's different than for single integrals. If not, tell me and I'll explain it. Thanks!

Comment: @Highvoltagemath yeah now I do. I asked this question a long time ago, and now I’m a math student in uni so it all makes sense. Though if you have a good answer feel free to add it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
dudv= det \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\end{array}
\right]dxdy
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Is there a intuitive explanation for why?

Comment: @D.R. It is one of those things that you learnt back in the mists of time & just accepted ... I have had a look around on the net & just find statements of the above ... there is a nice explanation for the specific case of polar coordinates https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Teaching/Stat406-Spring08/homework/changeOfVariablesHandout.pdf

Comment: I got: $\begin{eqnarray*}
dudv= det \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \frac{1}{t} \\
1 & \frac{-s}{t^2} \\
\end{array}
\right]dsdt
\end{eqnarray*}$, which is $dudv=\frac{1}{t}+\frac{s}{t^2}dsdt$, which is $dudv=\frac{1}{t}(1+v)dsdt$, and $\frac{1}{t}$ is $\frac{1+v}{u}$, which makes $dudv=\frac{(1+v)^2}{u}dsdt$ which doesn't work. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @D.R. Try with $s$ & $t$ the other way up !

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#/media/File:Jacobian_determinant_and_distortion.svg

Comment: on the left, you have dxdy and you want the area of the redish shaded area. It is approximately equal to the area of the white parallelogram, which is given by the determinant of that matrix.

Answer (score 2):

The multiplication factor is the Jacobian

\begin{eqnarray*}
du\, dv = J (x,y,u,v) =Det \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} \\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\end{array}
\right]dx\,dy
\end{eqnarray*}

For example from metric  $ ds^2 = E\, du^2 + 2 F \,du \,dv + G\, dv^2 $ differential  area transforms  by a factor $ \sqrt {EG-F^2. }$